# Sobel Filter not functioning correctly

Tags: java, sobel

I wrote a class for Sobel operator for edge detection, but when I use an example image, my edges are off.  Greatly appreciate it if someone can help me with this.

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ConvolveOp;
import java.awt.image.Kernel;
import java.awt.image.Raster;
import java.util.Arrays;

class SobelFilter {

private static final float[] sobel1 = { 1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f};
private static final float[] sobel2 = { 1.0f, 2.0f,  1.0f};
private static final boolean[] sobelBoolean = {true, false};

private SobelFilter() {}
 
private static ConvolveOp getSobelX(boolean fs) {
    Kernel kernel = null;
    
    if (fs) {
        kernel = new Kernel(1, 3, sobel1);
    }
    else {
        kernel = new Kernel(3, 1, sobel2);
    }
    
    return new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_ZERO_FILL, null);
}

private static ConvolveOp getSobelY(boolean fs) {
    Kernel kernel = null;
    
    if (fs) {
        kernel = new Kernel(1, 3, sobel2);
    }
    else {
        kernel = new Kernel(3, 1, sobel1);
    }
    
    return new ConvolveOp(kernel, ConvolveOp.EDGE_ZERO_FILL, null);
}

public static BufferedImage getSobelFilter(BufferedImage img) {
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();
    int size = width * height;
    int[] x = new int[size];
    int[] y = new int[size];
    int[] pixelM = new int[size];
    //double[] pixelD = new double[size];

    BufferedImage sobelX = null;
    BufferedImage sobelY = null;
    
    for(boolean i : sobelBoolean) {
        sobelX = getSobelX(i).filter(img, null);
        sobelY = getSobelY(i).filter(img, null);
    }
    
    sobelX.getRaster().getPixels(0, 0, width, height, x);
    sobelY.getRaster().getPixels(0, 0, width, height, y);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        pixelM[i] = (int) Math.hypot(x[i], y[i]);
        //pixelD[i] = Math.atan2((double) y[i], (double) x[i]);
    }
    
    BufferedImage result = 
        new BufferedImage(width, height,
                          BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
    result.getRaster().setPixels(0, 0, width, height, pixelM);
    
    return result;
}
}
```

I used the valve picture from Wikipedia as an example.

### Original test image

[image: original]

### Expected result

[image: expected]

### Actual result

[image: Actual Result]

Comment: Please post the original image and the edge map. Also note that Sobel is super simple to implement but it's not the best choice when it comes to edge detection. Consider using at least a Canny detector, which essentially is Sobel plus some extra steps.

Comment: I do not yet have enough reputation to post the image.  Is there anyway i can get around that?

I am actually working towards canny's algorithm as a finished product.  I am just using trying to obtain a BufferedImage with Sobel so I can process the magnitude and gradient in one swoop.

Comment: Post the links as comments and I will edit the post for you :)

Comment: Thanks!

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f0/Valve_original_%281%29.PNG
http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d4/Valve_sobel_%283%29.PNG/300px-Valve_sobel_%283%29.PNG

and unfortunately, I do not have a link for the image that this class produced.

Comment: Upload it somewhere (imgur.com? uploadpie.com?) and share a link please. Also provide a `main` method, so that we can run your code.

Comment: http://uploadpie.com/dpT25

And I might need a second with the main method, it is buried in 6 different classes.  thanks!

Comment: I shared a link to the entire class via google drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you plotted is the Y component of the gradient. Consider this:

```
g2.drawImage(sobelX, null, 0, 0);
g2.drawImage(sobelY, null, 0, 0);
```

`sobelX` is hidden behind `sobelY`, so you only see the latter.

What you want is the **norm of the gradient**. You'll have to scan both images and calculate `z = sqrt(x*x + y*y)` for each pixel `x` of `sobelX` and its corresponding `y` of `sobelY`.

Pseudocode:

```
norm = image of the same size of sobelX and sobelY;

for (int x = 0; x < horizontal dimension of the image; ++x) {
    for (int y = 0; y < vertical dimension of the image; ++y) {
        xPixel = sobelX.pixelAt(x,y);
        yPixel = sobelY.pixelAt(x,y);
        norm.pixelAt(x,y) = Math.hypot(xPixel, yPixel);
    }
}

return norm;
```

Comment: So I should use something along the lines of getRaster() and setRaster() before returning the image?

Comment: Yep exactly. Get a `WriteableRaster` from both images and build a third one as I detailed in the pseudocode. If you think it's necessary, I might dive in the javadocs and write actual Java code.

Comment: I adjusted my code per your suggestions, the result is as above edited post.  Please advise.  Thanks!

Comment: Your Sobel kernels are wrong wrt to the result you want. They should be 3x3, not 3x1. You can find the right structure on any computer vision book/tutorial. Fix the kernels and it will work.

Comment: [link](http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/f/a/8/fa8b1d6d59ef5a80ac0bfcdb5e956f47.png)

What i did was split the 3x3 according to the equation above and convolved it twice.  I guess that did not work.  Got it working now.  Thanks!

Comment: I see. Then your problem was that you were convolving the original image twice (thus keeping only the second), while you should have applied the second convolution to `sobelX` from previous iteration. Anyway, you are welcome!

Comment: Thanks for you help on this.  I moved on to Canny's and I seem to have an issue with my operations Hysteresis, I would greatly appreciate if you can help me on it like you've helped me here :).

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27531747/cannys-algorithm-hysteresis-mal-function]